# Trouble assigning static IP using nmtui

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, nmcli

I am trying to assign static IP to Ubuntu Server (installed in VirtualBox).
To do that I have done the following changes to Server Machine:

1. Installed Network Manager tools to use nmcli/nmtui.
2. Set netplan to use network manager.
3. Used nmtui to assign static IP to enp0s3 link.

Everything was perfect and working until I rebooted the server.

Can anyone help me out to make these changes persistant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu Server 18.04 and newer uses systemd-networkd instead of NetworkManager. The selection is made by netplan, so you can change it in netplan. You can also simply [use netplan to define the static IP address](http://netplan.io/examples) without all the mucking about with NetworManager.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user535733. It worked!.